# FCB::Open failed: Could not open file

Tags: sql-server

The machine was restarted while I was shrinking a database and since then the `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` not starting. After reading the blogs I replaced the `master.mdf` and  `mastlog.ldf` files from the templates folder with the same file, assuming master database was corrupted as I was shrinking this.

However the problem remains and the error log file gives the following message,

```
Starting up database 'msdb'.
Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
FCB::Open failed: Could not open file E:\sql12_main_t.obj.x86Release\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBData.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
Unable to open the physical file "E:\sql12_main_t.obj.x86Release\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBData.mdf". Operating system error 3: "3(The system cannot find the path specified.)".
Error: 17207, Severity: 16, State: 1.
FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.) occurred while creating or opening file 'E:\sql12_main_t.obj.x86Release\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBLog.ldf'. Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the operation.
File activation failure. The physical file name "E:\sql12_main_t.obj.x86Release\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBLog.ldf" may be incorrect.
The resource database build version is 12.00.2000. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
Starting up database 'model'.
```

I can clearly say that there is no E:\ partition on my machine. Can you please help me to fix the path which I assume is the error now?

Comment: Don't you have backups of your system databases? Obviously the master database you replaced is pointing to the E:\. What was the error before you replaced the master files?

Comment: Agree with @WEI_DBA that restoring master from backup would be ideal to get past this problem, assuming you have backups. You might still need to fix your original problem after restoring master (but since we don't know what thew original problem is, I can't say.

Comment: If this is just a local "sandbox" instance, you can rebuild master and reattach databases. I assume if this IS your local machine, that you don't have backups. Once you get SQL to come back online, can you tell us what the original error was? I don't see how shrinking a user database would affect Master directly if the server restarted.

Answer (score 1):

You replaced `master` with the one that comes from the SQL Server build process. This one is pointing to the release build mkmaster folders *for `msdb` database*. As `msdb` is no a system database, you should be able to start the engine, connect to it, detach `msdb` and re-attach the correctly located one. But this is **not** the correct process. The correct process is described in [Rebuild System Databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and involves running setup.exe:

```
Setup /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE ...
```